# How to check token based authentication for GET and Post Methods in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, getmethod, http-token-authentication

How to use token based authentication for GET and Post Methods and also subsequent methods in asp.net

Comment: You just want to add the `[Authorize]` [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to the methods/controller?

Comment: it will check subsequent methods also right??

Comment: If you add at the controller level, any method in that controller will require authentication.

Comment: token based authentication for GET and POST, can you pls elaborate ?

Comment: In MVC if you use [Authorize] annotation with directly controller, this will authorize every requests, but its not authentication. please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: i have used WebAPI ,so every method i  have to  generate token based on user then need validate methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here for JSon Web Token authentication, and how to still use the authorise attribute but not cookie based auth.

http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/

Its a 5 part tutorial, and it works really well!